# Moderator Help please

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Parenting Stack Exchange post: [How to get in touch with a moderator](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/39631/how-to-get-in-touch-with-a-moderator)

I am sorry about posting in the main section but I really need a mod.

Comment: Hi, Jason, what can we do for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. I need to know if I can see messages that have been deleted. Or if a mod can look up the time a deleted message was posted. I know that sounds weird but it's important.

Comment: Some posts that are deleted can be seen by a moderator, yes, and by some higher rep users. As far as seeing one yourself you’d have to ask I suppose and provide a reason that was satisfactory, but in general a lower rep user cannot see deleted  content.

Comment: That is understandable. Can you invite me to a private chat?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105181/discussion-on-question-by-jason-michaels-moderator-help-please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can get in touch with a moderator by one of a few ways:
- For quick questions, ask I. Chat
- For questions that are bigger in nature, ask a question in Meta
- For al other questions, flag any post and ask in the Other option in that flag (flag a relevant post if possible but any post will do).